# Rearranging sql query results to display appropriately

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the result of a certain query which I have to display in a List control in my webpage.

Query 1 result:
`4 items in descending order`
Query 2 result: 
`Top 1 result`

Actually, I have to display the first result from the first query, first result from the second query and then the remaining three from the first query results.

Initially, I thought to re-arrange the rows, but that won't be possible in the ItemTemplate of a Data control I suppose, since individual rows can't be changed.

Should I write my query in some form that I gives the result in the order, which would give the right order of items to be displayed?
For eg:
`Take the first result from top 4 item` +
`Find the second result`+ 
`Three items (minus the top one already that has been already extracted)`

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
1st class: (has 4 student)

Tom (Has highest score)
Rex (Hss second highest score)
Rambo (HAs 3rd highest score)
Betty (Has least score)

2nd class: (has 1 student)

Spooky (Has the highest score)

Required result order in DataControl:

Tom
Spooky
Rex
Rambo
Betty
```

Comment: Actally sample of queries would be helpful

Comment: @Omkarpanhalkar: Added an example

Comment: are the columns of both the results are the same?

Comment: @PraveenVenu: Yes the result columns are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Way you'll be able  to put the first from the first select and the first from second 
and the others 2 from first select;

First your query return:

```
public DataTable query1()
{
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                #region YOUR SQL1

                qs.Execute();
                dt = qs.Return;

                return dt1;
}

public DataTable query2()
{
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();

               #region YOUR SQL2

                qs.Execute();
                dt = qs.Return;

                return dt2;
}
```

You should  create a View State DataTable format, exactly   like your DataTable Return from Slect.  EXEXMPLE:

```
public DataTable _VS_RETURN_FORMAT
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["_VS_RETURN_FORMAT] == null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("field1");
            dt.Columns.Add("field2");

            ViewState["_VS_RETURN_FORMAT"] = dt;
        }
        return (DataTable)ViewState["_VS_RETURN_FORMAT"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["_VS_RETURN_FORMAT"] = value;
    }
}
```

You should be able to control the datatable result with a DataRow. EXEMPLE:

```
         DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            dt1 = SelectQuery1();
            dt2 = SelectQuery2();


            //Create a new DataRow  Like  your ViewState
            DataRow dr = _VS_RETURN_FORMAT;


            //Adding  to the fields the value that your need 

            dr["field1"] = dt1.Row[0][0];
            dr["field2"] = dt1.Row[0][1];


            _VS_RETURN_FORMAT.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr["field1"] = dt2.Row[0][0];
            dr["field2"] = dt2.Row[0][1];

            _VS_RETURN_FORMAT.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr["field1"] = dt1.Row[1][0];
            dr["field2"] = dt1.Row[1][1];

            _VS_RETURN_FORMAT.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr["field1"] = dt1.Row[2][0];
            dr["field2"] = dt1.Row[2][1];

            _VS_RETURN_FORMAT.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 Name ClassRank from Class1 order by Score desc
union 
select top 1 Name  ClassRank from Class2 order by Score desc
union
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Score desc) AS rownumber    
  FROM Class1
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber >1
```

Comment: The `first` from 1st class always has to stay at top of overall list and the first from `second` class always has to stay at 2nd place of overall list. So, overall union and then sorting won't be any good for me. Or if I could interchange the top two places somehow? :-/

Comment: Order By and union can't come together in the first `select` query